# Unable to install oh-my-zsh package on alpine docker container

Tags: alpine, zsh

Running `apk add oh-my-zsh` on a docker container I get:

```
/ # apk add oh-my-zsh
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  oh-my-zsh (no such package):
    required by: world[oh-my-zsh]
```

The package seems to exist: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86/oh-my-zsh

Here is the docker file I'm building from:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update
RUN apk add curl
RUN apk add zsh
RUN apk add git
RUN apk add oh-my-zsh
```

Comment: did you update the sources?

Comment: Yes. I've added docker file to question.

Answer (score 0):

The "latest" docker images for alpine uses 3.16.x which does not contain the oh-my-zsh package. Only the "edge" version of alpine has oh-my-zsh.